# Microsoft REST api how to get document ID from shared URL copied from desktop application

Tags: excel, api, rest, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

We have web application written by python that can get document by from google drive or Microsoft onedrive. Document is data tables (excel or google sheet)
All ok with url like this:

> https://onedrive.live.com/edit.aspx?resid=CFE36FE507A85213!105&cid=7b499b2f-510e-462a-9f92-4ab3729fa42f

I parse the urlencoded string and open document by resid (document_id).
For example, I read worksheet name list by REST in this way :

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/CFE36FE507A85214!105/workbook/worksheets

But I have trouble with url from desktop application(office 365 shared with onedrive as I understand) which give me my colleague look like this:

> https://d.docs.live.net/db26644aa99aff48/Documents/test%20sheet.xlsx

PS I'm not user of windows or Microsoft office